# Docker COPY recursive --chmod --chown

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to recursively copy some files and directories into a Docker image. The source directory contains files and a sub-directory with some files in it.

```
src/
├─ subdir/
│  ├─ sub_file_1
│  ├─ sub_file_2
├─ file_1
├─ file_2
...
├─ file_n
```

I am running the following command in Dockerfile:

`COPY --chown=user:user --chmod=600 src/ /dst/`

The permissions are correctly applied for all top level files (`file_1` to `file_n`) and the sub directory itself, but not for the files in `subdir` (e.g. sub_file_1).

Entering the container and running ls, the output is:

```
user@container:/$ ls -la /dst/subdir
ls: cannot access '/dst/subdir/sub_file_1': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/dst/subdir/sub_file_2': Permission denied

total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sub_file_1
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sub_file_2
```

Is there a way to recursively apply `--chmod` and `--chown` options of the `COPY` command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **Short answer:**
  You have to actually give exec permissions to your folder and files by replacing your `chmod` with `--chmod=700`. And you can look up more details below or just google `Linux file permissions.
- **Long answer:** So i recreated your example and as you can see bellow i have some scripts that i'm running in various stages before my server actually starts. I'm following good production docker practices as you do i can see and i also use your method to change permissions on the scripts file.

```
    
# App files
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /usr/src/app/build ./build
# Migration files
COPY --chown=node:node ./migrations ./migrations
# Scripts
COPY --chown=node:node --chmod=600 ./scripts ./scripts
# Client
COPY --chown=node:node ./client ./build/client
EXPOSE 80
```

And no surprise, i get a similar error.

```
    sh: ./scripts/wait-for.sh: Permission denied
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 126
    npm ERR! webpage-server@0.0.1 preprod: `./scripts/wait-for.sh page-db:5432 -- npm run migrate -- --config build/src/config/database.json -e production `
    npm ERR! Exit status 126
```

The problem here is the code you are giving to your chmod. Your goal is to make them executable and for security reasons make them executable for only the node(default) docker user. Now these decimal numbers we give to our `chmod` are just sugar to our eyes, in reality, these will be converted to binary and assigned to every one of the permission variables for the directory and its child files/folders(in this case). You have 4 values in the Linux file system permissions, one bit to indicate file or directory, 3 bit to define user access to file/dir, another 3 for the group of users and 3 more for everyone else, you want to give execute permissions to the current user so you will need `111=7` so the final `chmod` will look more like this:

```
    # App files
    COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /usr/src/app/build ./build
    # Migration files
    COPY --chown=node:node ./migrations ./migrations
    # Scripts
    COPY --chown=node:node --chmod=700 ./scripts ./scripts
    # Client
    COPY --chown=node:node ./client ./build/client
    EXPOSE 80
```

And as you can see the problem no longer persists

```
    > webpage-server@0.0.1 preprod /usr/src/app
    > ./scripts/wait-for.sh page-db:5432 -- npm run migrate -- --config build/src/config/database.json -e production 
    
    
    > webpage-server@0.0.1 migrate /usr/src/app
    > db-migrate up "--config" "build/src/config/database.json" "-e" "production"
    
    [INFO] No migrations to run
    [INFO] Done
    
    > webpage-server@0.0.1 prod /usr/src/app
    > npm run start
    
    
    > webpage-server@0.0.1 start /usr/src/app
    > node build/src/server.js
    
    18:28:17 info: Initializing thanos webpage Server version: 0.0.1. Environment: development
    18:28:17 info: /usr/src/app/build/src
    18:28:17 info: Thanos web page server is listening on port -> 80
```

Comment: Confirmed it works. Thanks a lot. Could you please explain why execution is needed on the directory for recursive permissions? Will docker change into the directory to set the permissions individually on each file?

Comment: Hello again, its not clear to me as well, it was after some experimentation in order to reproduce your error and i didnt reproduce it exactly if you notice my comment. But one think i woud like to point out is that your sub directories dont change ownership a good practice would be to COPY as root and then change ownership recursively like that RUN chown -R admin:admin /dst and then again as root change the permissions, you can try to experiment with that solution since its not very safe to give exec to files that do not absolutely need it. Hope its helps!!

Comment: Let me know if this works better because its a more robust and long term solution and i would update my comment accordingly

Comment: The subdirectories do change ownership, after following your suggestion of adding execute permissions. All files now have the correct owner and permissions set in the resulting docker image.